# WordPress Plugin Register Taxonomy for Object Type of Theme Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, action-hook

In my WordPress Plugin, I use the following code to automatically add Meta Boxes for all installed Taxonimies:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_register_taxonomies_for_object_type');
function my_plugin_register_taxonomies_for_object_type()
{
  $args = array(
    'public'   => true,
  );
  $output = 'objects';
  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output );
  foreach  ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy )
  {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy->name, 'jt_condet_content' );
  }
}
```

This works really well for all Taxonmies, even those installed via plugins. However, I noticed that one Taxonomy is missing. It is a normal Post Taxonomy installed by a Child Theme using `register_taxonomy()` in the `init` hook of the Theme.

Any idea why only this Taxonomy is missed by my plugins `my_plugin_register_taxonomies_for_object_type()`? It drives me crazy. I want to show meta boxes for all installed public Taxonomies, no matter if they are build in, installed via a Plugins or via a Themes.

**I played around a little bit with the action hook and `wp_loaded` seems to work but i'm not 100% confident that this is the right hook to use or am I fine?**

Can you explain me the downsided of using `wp_loaded` over `init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `init` and the child theme is also using `init` you probably just need to change the priority of *your* hook to ensure it runs *after* theirs. Try doing:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_register_taxonomies_for_object_type', 20 );
```

Assuming their theme uses the default (10) yours will run after theirs and their taxonomy should be available.

The only downside I can think for using `wp_loaded` is that `wp_loaded` will run *after* a few other actions such as `widgets_init`, `register_sidebar` and probably a few others. If there are any other callbacks by other plugins / themes that would expect *your* post type to have these taxonomies registered, **and** they hook before `wp_loaded`, they'd fail because `wp_loaded` runs after them. It's likely `wp_loaded` would be fine in most cases.

Comment: If I register my own custom post type in init and only factor out the mentioned piece of code (adding the taxonomy meta boxes to my post type), I should be on the safe side, right?